# PHP grouped a nested array and it is not out putting all values

Tags: php, arrays, nested, grouping

I have a nested array that I want to group by two

```
  array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Image' => array(
            'id' => '73',
            'upload' => 'img/uploads/GrillMenu-2.jpg',
            'name' => 'Burger',
            'placement_id' => '6',
            'Wheel_id' => '1',
            'Button_id' => '0',
            'Feature_id' => '0'
        ),
        'Placement' => array(
            'id' => '6',
            'Location' => '5-Lug'
        ),
        'Wheel' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'series' => 'Vector'
        ),
        'Button' => array(
            'id' => null,
            'name' => null
        ),
        'Feature' => array(
            'id' => null,
            'name' => null,
            'Content' => null
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Image' => array(
            'id' => '74',
            'upload' => 'img/uploads/img4.png',
            'name' => 'Yellow Rubi',
            'placement_id' => '6',
            'Wheel_id' => '1',
            'Button_id' => '0',
            'Feature_id' => '0'
        ),
        'Placement' => array(
            'id' => '6',
            'Location' => '5-Lug'
        ),
        'Wheel' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'series' => 'Vector'
        ),
        'Button' => array(
            'id' => null,
            'name' => null
        ),
        'Feature' => array(
            'id' => null,
            'name' => null,
            'Content' => null
        )
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'Image' => array(
            'id' => '75',
            'upload' => 'img/uploads/afw-forged-wheels.png',
            'name' => 'afw-forged-wheels',
            'placement_id' => '6',
            'Wheel_id' => '1',
            'Button_id' => '0',
            'Feature_id' => '0'
        ),
        'Placement' => array(
            'id' => '6',
            'Location' => '5-Lug'
        ),
        'Wheel' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'series' => 'Vector'
        ),
        'Button' => array(
            'id' => null,
            'name' => null
        ),
        'Feature' => array(
            'id' => null,
            'name' => null,
            'Content' => null
        )
    )
)
```

I want to group it by the Wheel Series and by Placement Location:
I ran this to make it group my array:

```
$plates = array();

foreach ( $WheelAll as $row ) {
  $key1 = $row['Wheel']['series'];
  $key2 = $row['Placement']['Location'];

  $plates[$key1][$key2] = $row;
}
```

However the output of the New array is missing one of my sub array. I should have two
Images under Vector 5-Lug:

```
array(
    'Vector' => array(
        '5-Lug' => array(
            'Image' => array(
                'id' => '75',
                'upload' => 'img/uploads/afw-forged-wheels.png',
                'name' => 'afw-forged-wheels',
                'placement_id' => '6',
                'Wheel_id' => '1',
                'Button_id' => '0',
                'Feature_id' => '0'
            ),
            'Placement' => array(
                'id' => '6',
                'Location' => '5-Lug'
            ),
            'Wheel' => array(
                'id' => '1',
                'series' => 'Vector'
            ),
            'Button' => array(
                'id' => null,
                'name' => null
            ),
            'Feature' => array(
                'id' => null,
                'name' => null,
                'Content' => null
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign to `$plates[$key1][$key2] = $row;`, you overwrite anything that was there previously.

In this situation, I would make `$plates[$key1][$key2]` hold an array of the items, which can easily be accomplished as so

```
$plates = array();

foreach ( $WheelAll as $row ) {
    $key1 = $row['Wheel']['series'];
    $key2 = $row['Placement']['Location'];

    $plates[$key1][$key2][] = $row; // [] assigns to a new element in an array.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've probably got MULTIPLE entries in your `WheelAll` array that happen to have `$key1` and `$key2` that conflict. So when the second key1/key2 pair comes up, you overwrite the first pair that was saved. In other words, you need:

```
  $plates[$key1][$key2][] = $row;
                       ^^---append new row
```

in your build loop instead. This way you'll get individual array entries for ALL $key1/$key2 pairs, not just the LAST one encountered.